# Making a nested div scrollable on page resize

Tags: html, css

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rayabu1234/pfozmoxh/)

I spent some time on this, but cannot resolve this css issue. I have 4 nested divs. the inner most child div, holds a table of rows.

Html structure

```
 div class="moduleContentContainer">
 <div id="dash-board-container">
 <div class="dash-board-item">
     <div class=".quote_list_container">
         <table>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
             <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>]
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>

         <table>
     </div>
</div>
```

(1) I want the dash_Board_Item Div to have its height based on the size of its content(the content in the .quote_list_container div"). so if there is one row, in the table, dash-board-item div should be small in height and taller otherwise, depending on content.

(2) when the window resize, display a scroll bar on the .quote_list_container div when required.

Ray

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rayabu1234/pfozmoxh/ ?

Answer (score 1):

First, You have a mistake within your HTML: `div class=".quote_list_container"` you should remove the leading period `.` from the class name.

Second, since the element containing the contents is nested within couple of elements, you may run into trouble by using `max-height` with percentage values. Because you would have to specify an explicit height for the parents.

Therefore, you could use [`vh` viewport percentage unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) to accomplish that:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pfozmoxh/2/)**

```css
.quote_list_container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Spec from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

> **vh unit**
>   Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.

It's worth noting that `vh` viewport relative length is [supported in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) and above.

Answer (score 0):

i try to solve your problem,  see example.

```css
.quote_list_container {
color: #6e6e6e;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
/* position: relative; */
max-height: 91%;
}

.dash-board-item {
margin-right: 20px;
display: inline-block;
border-style: solid;
max-width: 700px;
min-width: 300px;
border-color: #999999;
border-width: 1px;
/* box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgb(109,109,110); */
/* float: left; */
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
    height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    
}

#dash-board-container {
position: absolute;
height: 90%;
}

.moduleContentContainer {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="moduleContentContainer">
<div id="dash-board-container">
     <div class="dash-board-item">
         <div class=".quote_list_container">
             <table>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                 
             <table>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. you have the scroll bar working when resizing. but the .dash_board_item height should be set to its content and not set to the height of page

Comment: for this solution you can give `max-height: 100%;` to `.dash-board-item` and remove `height: 100%`

Comment: if you like my answer than you can accept it for other review.